# Как суммировать значения массива в twig?

Tags: twig

Так twig выводить список значений:

```
{% for man in row.mans %}
    {{man.money}}
{% endfor %}
```

Я хочу их сложить (посчитать сумму, а не длину массива), но twig не выводит вообще ничего (белый экран):

```
{% set sum = 0 %}
{% for man in row.mans %}
    {% set sum = sum + man.money %}
{% endfor %}
```

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Все работает - посчитанную переменную же надо вывести!!! )))

```
   {{sum}}
```

Comment: минус вам влетел из-за моей правки кода (автоматика так делает), компенсировал плюсом. а вообще вопрос на закрытие, т.к. "вызван опечаткой"